# Translation for 无效

Tags: translation, grammar

I'm looking for a translation of "无效".

Does that mean

> "incorrect"

?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

无效  can mean 'invalid' or "ineffectual/ unsuccessful"

example:

球在哨响后才入球笼门，因此无效 - The ball was kicked in after the whistle, therefore, the goal is invalid

化疗电疗均告无效 - Both chemotherapy and electrotherapy have been ineffectual

抢救无效，病人当场死亡 - The emergency rescue effort was unsuccessful, the patient died on the spot

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score -1):

'invalid' should be a more proper one